# DateTimeFormatter parser

Tags: java, parsing, datetime-format

I have to parse the following date: 2015-05-04 00:00:00.0 
But my formatter can't recognize it.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:ss.S").withLocale(Locale.US);
```

I know it is the last character what is the problem, but don't really know what to put there.

Comment: You might want to read the doc and the error message (hint: `MM` vs `mm`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pattern you're looking for is: `"YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.S"`, the key difference being the symbol used for minutes (you told it to parse them as months).  From the javadoc of `DateTimeFormat`:

```
M/L     month-of-year               number/text       7; 07; Jul; July; J
m       minute-of-hour              number            30
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this answer is wrong. The correct pattern is `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S` or even better `uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S`. You can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67452253/10819573) to learn more about it.