# how to compare two different timestamp and find the latest

Tags: java, datetime, datetime-format

I have the two different timestamp values as String. I need to find which one is latest. Its in the format of [YYYYMMDDHHMMSS]

**Timestamps are :**

```
20150804030251
20150804040544
```

Is there any easy way to get the latest using Java 8?

Comment: Have you tried something at least?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, those timestamps are formated in a way which is easy to compare.

```
if ( Long.parseLong(timesteamp1) < Long.parseLong(timestamp2) ) {
  //timestamp2 is later than timestamp1
}
```

This is possible because the most significative part, the year, is in the most significative part of an integer, the leftmost; the rest of the parts go in decreasing order of significance from left to right; and a fixed number of digits is used for each part, like month 02 instead of month 2. Otherwise this simple way would not be possible.

You can also compare them lexicografically. The previous code, in the particular case of this format, is equivalent to :

```
if ( timestamp1.compareTo(timestamp2) < 0 ) {
  // timestamp2 is later than timestamp 1
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't even have to parse those strings. Just use compareTo():

```
"20150804030251".compareTo("20150804040544");
```

[More info](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_compareto.htm)

Answer (score 3):

you can create local date object In java 8, like below

```
LocalDateTime dt = LocalDateTime.parse("20150804030251",
                DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYYMMDDHHMMSS")

LocalDateTime dt2 = LocalDateTime.parse("20150804030251",
                DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYYMMDDHHMMSS")
```

then compare using `dt.isBefore(dt2)`

Comment: I have already tried this one, but it wasn't working. i got parsing exception.

Comment: The basic idea is the right one. I too get `java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '20150804030251' could not be parsed at index 0`, though (after completing the statements). You need to beware of the case of format pattern letters.

Answer (score 1):

You can still try this. In here not use any special feature in `Java 8`

```
String timeStamp1 = "20150804030251";
String timeStamp2 = "20150804040544";
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMhhHHmmss");
Date date1 = dateFormat.parse(timeStamp1);
Date date2 = dateFormat.parse(timeStamp2);
if(date1.after(date2)){
  System.out.println("latest "+date1);
}else {
  System.out.println("latest "+date2);
}
```

Comment: You misunderstood what those numbers are. The first, for example, should signify August 4, 2015, 03:02:51. Instead your code gives Thu Jul 21 23:33:50 CEST 2608 (almost 600 years off).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, none of the existing answers is proper. Let's first discuss the problem with them:

- The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31848934/10819573) works as a result of mere coincidence. It happened to work just because the values are arranged in the decreasing order of time units (year, month, day, hour, minute, second). It will fail if their positions are changed e.g. `MMyyyy...`. Another serious problem with this approach is that it will fail to validate a wrong value e.g. 15 digits instead of 14 digits.
- [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31849176/10819573) has similar problems as with the accepted answer. Instead of numeric value, it compares ASCII values and thus may fail for the same reasons as mentioned for the accepted answer.
- [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31849098/10819573) is the idiomatic way of doing it, but it is wrong because it uses `Y` (which specifies *week-based-year*) instead of `y` (which specifies *year-of-era*) and `D` (which specifies *day-of-year*) instead of `d` (which specifies *day-of-month*). In fact, it is [recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65928023/10819573) to use `u` instead of `y`. Check the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) page
  to learn more about these symbols.
- [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31849038/10819573) is blatantly wrong. [`Date(long date)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date-long-) should initialize the object with the no. of milliseconds since `1970-01-01T00:00:00Z`.

By now, you must have already figured out the solution which I have posted below just for the sake of completeness:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strDateTime1 = "20150804030251";
        String strDateTime2 = "20150804040544";

        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuuMMddHHmmss");

        LocalDateTime ldt1 = LocalDateTime.parse(strDateTime1, dtf);
        LocalDateTime ldt2 = LocalDateTime.parse(strDateTime2, dtf);

        LocalDateTime latest = ldt1.isAfter(ldt2) ? ldt1 : ldt2;

        System.out.println(latest);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2015-08-04T04:05:44
```

Learn more about the the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Comment: A very, very good answer. Setting everything straight and giving the exact best solution to the question.

Comment: The question says "Its in the format of [YYYYMMDDHHMMSS]" so it doesn't work  "as a result of mere coincidence." 
The answer is good for a more general case. But a big part of coding is to understand what you are doing. And KISS ;)